# Slimy translucent material help?

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, shaders

I want to create a material that is transparent but also has a "wet" or slimy look, like the bug in MiB 1 or the demogorgon from Stranger Things. I don't know if you could achieve this with a principled bsdf or what. Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a principled BSDF and make it translucent or transparent with the transmission settings. You can also use the clearcoat settings and clearcoat normal input to make it look different outside.
[image: principled transmission and clearcoat]